# There is a type for function pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Does the standard library implements a type for pointers to functions in C++ ?

I'm not happy with functors (they are more like an hack to me than a real pointer to a function), you have to create an extra object, and this is really not what I'm looking for, in C with a couple of parenthesis and a simple syntax you can declare a pointer to function, I'm looking for the same simplicity plus some useful method related to the type, for example the ability to replace the pointed function while keeping the object in a consistent state all the time.

There is something like that ? I really miss the plain old function pointers in C and in C++ AFAIK there is no such thing for methods that are members of a class or any other function.

Comment: I think you will get some bad comments on your question, but the only wrong question is the one never asked.

Comment: Regular function pointers in C works in C++ as well, as long as they aren't member functions.

Comment: and you can have pointers to member functions...

Comment: @MatsPetersson yeah, I expect that, but since C++ is offering classes ... I was expecting something a little bit more ... "complete"

Comment: you can have pointers to static member functions

Comment: @user2485710: It sounds like you're asking for C#-style delegates that keep a reference (closure) to the `this` parameter.  That's basically a functor, and is substantially more than a pointer.

Comment: @PoByBolek like how in your opinion ?

Comment: Well, can you give an example of what you are trying to do? In general and at least in my book, C++ isn't meant to use function pointers, because for most things there is another way to solve that problem that is "better" (e.g. polymorphism).

Comment: Functors aren't a hack, for starters. If you want an anonymous object with a form of capture you can use lambdas.

Comment: See also my blog posts, http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-2-c.html/ and http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html/

Comment: You're missing the point that interfaces that take a function pointer suck because they're quite annoying to use with capturing lambdas or any other more powerful function object.

Comment: @Rapptz a C style pointer to function is not exactly "anonymous"

Comment: @user2485710 Function pointers suck anyway. An anonymous non-capturing lambda decays to a function pointer anyway.

Comment: @Rapptz, It doesn't have to be `void` (however you mean that), just noncapturing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking for [pointers-to-member-functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html), these exist as part of the core language, though I wouldn't call them "simple":

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
   T(int x) : x(x) {};
   void foo() { std::cout << x; }

private:
   int x;
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (T::*P)();
    P fooptr = &T::foo;

    T obj(5);
    (obj.*fooptr)(); // Output: 5
}
```

([live demo](http://ideone.com/v9v6fy))

---

`std::function`, when combined with `std::bind`, is a somewhat nicer alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct T
{
   T(int x) : x(x) {};
   void foo() { std::cout << x; }

private:
   int x;
};

int main()
{
   using namespace std::placeholders; // for _1, _2, _3...
   std::function<void()> f = std::bind(&T::foo, _1); // or auto f = ...

   T obj(5);
   f(obj); // Output: 5
}
```

([live demo](http://ideone.com/ViObPG))

I recommend reading up on this topic a bit further as it's not a direct equivalent, but allows you to bind a functor to a member function, with early *or* late binding for the `this` pointer.

Comment: can you expand a little bit more ?

Comment: Your example is missing `std::placeholders`.

Comment: probably the nicest example, the only problem is that they are templated, so they are not "flexible" at runtime as I would like a pointer to function to be

Comment: C++11 seems to be in full use here. I wish I could use it more than I currently can. The deprecated variants will be frowned at I guess?

Comment: @user2485710 What kind of "runtime flexibility" are you referring to?

Comment: @user2485710: An object wrapper around pointers to arbitrary _anything_ simply **has** to be a template.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function pointer type shipped with the language- `Ret(*)(Args...)`. There is also a member function pointer type `Ret(T::*)(Args...)` (although they're virtually worthless). In addition, you can use `std::function`, `std::bind`, and lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered, and this is a "real" answer, but rather a kind of "but have you thought about this way" sort of answer.

Whilst there are certainly a lot of good uses for function pointers (and in C there is often no other alternative), and I've used pointer to member functions in a C++ Basic interpreter (to good effect and I'm happy that is a good solution).

Having said that, it is often better to use other alternatives,  such as polymorphism to solve the problems.

For example, we can use an interface class to make an object have a particular behaviour:

```
class iface
{
   public:
      virtual int func1() = 0;
};

class A: public iface
{
   int x;
   ...
   public:
      A(v) : x(v) {}
      // from iface
      int func1() 
      {
         return x * 42;
      }
};


class B: public iface
{
   int x;
   ...
   public:
      B(v) : x(v) {}
      // from iface
      int func1() 
      {
         return x * 17;
      }
};

vector<iface*> list;

int main()
{
    list.push_bacK(new A(12));
    list.push_back(new B(15));

    for(i : list)
    {
        cout << i->func1() << endl;
    }
}
```